# Modify particular page using Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3, smarty2

I'd like to remove some elements such as `<footer>` tag, menu row etc. on pages where body has unique classes like: 'shop_news_list' and 'shop_news'. The site is based on Smarty. I've tried to put those elements I want to delete in between something like this:

```
{if !($body_class == 'shop_news_list' || $body_class == 'shop_news')} 
  <footer> 
    <div class="innerfooter container row">
            ...
    </div>
  </footer>
{/if}
```

However it doesn't work or makes an element disappear from every page. Is there any other way I can do this or maybe you know how can I properly check if body has specific class. (I can not create new templates to use them on different pages).

Comment: You mention it doesn't work _or_ makes an element disappear from every page - what pages are you on when this is happening? I'd want to know specifically whether the `if` on `$body_class` works or it's a fault in the logic

Comment: Fore example when I am using it to remove footer tag it makes hide this element from every single page. When I am using it to delete menu row it doesn't work at all. But when I tried to put part of the code which is responsible for displaying search bar within this if statement it made it dissapear just like I wanted.

Comment: The question is if $body_class works the way I think it works. Does this variable check if body contains specific class like 'shop_news_list'?